# Looking for advice on getting GIS data into existing AutoCAD site survey

Tags: shapefile, autocad, dwg

I've got a variety of [GIS data from Albemarle County in ShapeFile and DWG format](http://www.albemarle.org/department.asp?department=gds&relpage=3914#Elevation). I'm looking to get the topographic layers and property boundaries together with my existing site survey created by a local surveyor.

What's the best practice for doing this? Is it "just XREF it all into one master file" and scale/move around or is there a better way to make this data normalized? I'm in one of the corners of the grid squares that the county has created, so I'd probably need to have 4 of them combined.

Edit: I have AutoCAD 2013. I have very little true GIS experience, but I have friends who have offered to help with QGIS.

Comment: Specifically what software do you have available on both the GIS and AutoCAD side? The answer will affect any workflow suggested. For instance csterling's suggested command may not be available if you don't have the right flavor of AutoCAD, and my first suggestion is going to be to reproject all of your GIS data in GIS software.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command MAPIINSERT (map i insert) after exporting your GIS data to DWG. If your CAD file has been created in a coordinate system (e.g., State Plane) you should make sure your GIS data uses the same projection. I'm not a CAD user but used to export CAD files for engineers and that command generally worked. I believe xref should work as well, but I know that MAPIINSERT has been used successfully.